# How to have a void pointer have same contents as a struct pointer?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make an abstract version of hash table that works with void pointers. And I can not get my pointers to contain values that would point to other structures.

I've tried to copy the pointers to other structures using `memcpy` but somehow that didn't work and when I tried to access other structures with pointers from an already cast to needed structure a void pointer I had received a seg fault.

It is worth noticing that I `calloc` memory for void pointers considering size of the content that I want to put in there.

```
void *connectionInfoStructToPutInHashTable = commonHashTableArguments->connectionInfoStruct;
void *existingElementPointer = localSearchForExistingElement(commonHashTableArguments);
if(existingElementPointer == NULL){
    return;
}
int connectionInfoStructSize = commonHashTableArguments->connectionInfoStructSize;
```

1. `memset(existingElementPointer, 0, connectionInfoStructSize);`

   ```
   memcpy(existingElementPointer, connectionInfoStructUpdated, connectionInfoStructSize);
   ```
2. `(*((int *)existingElementPointer)) = (*((int*)connectionInfoStructUpdated));`
3. `*(void**)existingElementPointer = connectionInfoStructUpdated;`

I've tried to use `memcpy`, previously erasing all data from the place of destination, but this didn't work and after casting void pointer back I got a seg fault accessing the pointers inside the cast pointer.

Also, I've tried void pointers to point to the structure themselves(under number 3 in code) and it worked but I would really like my void pointers which are parts of an array to have the necessary and then free that parts of memory that I don't need.

P.s. parts of memory that I don't need is what `connectionInfoStructToPutInHashTable` in code is referring to. Like a wrapper for pointers to the other structures.

Comment: Please show a [MCVE]

Comment: In C all pointers are implicitly convertible to *and from* `void *`. But if you want to use a `void *` directly (like dereferencing it like a pointer to a structure) you *must* cast the pointer to the correct type.

Comment: regarding 1).  There is nothing semantically wrong with your `memcpy` call.  You can use void pointers all day long ... as `memcpy` is defined on void pointers.  You don't need to do the `memset` on the line before since you are immediately overwriting the data on the next line.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but what if I have my void pointers calloc-ed to the same size as the size of the original correct type? I'm not sure whether I got it right but I think that is the issue that you were addressing.

Comment: Your code is incomplete and confusing, but I suspect that you will need to make your actual table an array of entry structs, where "entry" would be a custom struct that contains both a key of some kind (I'm not sure what the keys here would be, maybe `int`?) and also a `void *` for the (user-controlled) payload value.

Comment: regarding 2). assuming your types are correct, and those pointers are actually valid pointers to int, there is nothing semantically wrong with the statement: `(*((int *)existingElementPointer)) = (*((int*)connectionInfoStructUpdated));`

Comment: Remember that [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) actually returns a `void *`. You can use this pointer with *or without* casting, assigning directly to your structure, like e.g `struct MyStructure *pointer_variable = malloc(sizeof *pointer_variable)`.

Comment: regarding 3).  The line `*(void**)existingElementPointer = connectionInfoStructUpdated;` causes the value `existingElementPointer` to be cast to a *pointer to a pointer* to void.  You can't dereference a `void *` because the type it resolves to is `void`, but you can dererference a `void **` as the type it resolves to is `void *`.  So this line is syntactically valid, although it is probably not what you want to do.  We don't know because we don't have the actual code you are running.  Suggest an [mcve].